# Prove that there is no polynomial size quantum algorithm for a Simon's problem with no promise on the input

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, simons-algorithm

We look at the following variant of Simon's problem.

The input is an oracle $f:\{0,1\}^h \to [M]$.

The output of the algorithm: if there exists $s \in \{0,1\}^N$ such that $f(x)=f(y) \iff x=y \oplus s$, then output the first bit of $s$, otherwise output $1$.

The task is to show that there is no quantum algorithm for this problem, which is of polynomial size.

Seemingly, the only difference between this version of Simon's problem and the original version, it that in the original version its promised that such an $s$ exists (which makes $f$ a 2-to-1 function).

Here such a promise isn't present.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem, but it seems to me that the way is to assume by  that such an algorithm exists, which solves this problem in $p(n)$ times, and then use this algorithm in a quantum search algorithm and gain an exponential acceleration for a problem which would end in a contradiction.

Not exactly sure how to formulate it though. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, Simon is $x\oplus y=s$ but here $x=y\oplus s$, right?

Comment: Isn't it that essentially the same? if $x \oplus y = s$ then applying XOR on both sides with $y$ results in $x = y \oplus s$